# Modifying columns after a line flag or marker using bash or awk or gawk?

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I have a text file with the next format:

```
#  100  104  0.0
LAFE  0.3831 0.9920 P
MURC -33.1608 0.9966 P
POPE -5.4608 0.3327 P
#  100  105  0.0
LAFE -53.6463 0.9912 P
MURC -48.3792 0.9988 P
NARJ -51.5767 0.3749 P
#  100  106  0.0
LAFE -51.8675 0.9882 P
MURC -48.2517 0.9986 P
SAJU -49.1528 0.3051 P
#  100  107  0.0
```

I need to modify the second column multiplying by 0.01 but I need to keep lines with '#' intact, so the second of the line with # doesn't change.

Any ideas how to do this in awk or bash?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with awk:

```
awk '$1!="#" {$2 *= 0.1} 1' file.txt
```

if first field is not `#`, multiply second field by 0.1. Print all lines.

result on your provided dataset:

```
#  100  104  0.0
LAFE 0.03831 0.9920 P
MURC -3.31608 0.9966 P
POPE -0.54608 0.3327 P
#  100  105  0.0
LAFE -5.36463 0.9912 P
MURC -4.83792 0.9988 P
NARJ -5.15767 0.3749 P
#  100  106  0.0
LAFE -5.18675 0.9882 P
MURC -4.82517 0.9986 P
SAJU -4.91528 0.3051 P
#  100  107  0.0
```

aside, if there's a risk of the `#` not being alone on the first field, you have to check with a regex as Ed noted:

```
awk '$1 !~ /^#/ {$2 *= 0.1} 1' file.txt
```

Comment: Jean-Francois, Thanks very much bro!!

Comment: The script should end with `1`, not `$0`. The former will print all lines, the latter will only print lines that aren't empty or whose contents evaluate numerically to non-zero. With this particular input file you'll get the same output either way but it's a bad habit to get into. Also note that this is white-space dependent in that it relies on there being white space after the `#` to identify it as `$1`. Test for `$1 !~ /^#/` instead of `$1 != "#"`.

Comment: Ed, thanks for this observation. Will incorporate your input.

Comment: @EdMorton and I thought that dropping `{print}` was the top thing to do... edited with your suggestions;